# Kali software updater on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager

I accidentally  did these commands while fixing some issues on my Ubuntu system:

```bsh
chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
pt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

And after I did this my Software & Updates tab switched from *Ubuntu software* to *Kali Software*. Also when I try to run `apt-get update` this what terminal shows:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://38.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://38.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://38.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://38.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease
Hit:5 http://38.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

I know that this could be stupid problem, but I hope that you will help me with this.

Comment: Help you with what? You wanted Kali, you got Kali. Are you asking how to go back to Ubuntu? Are you asking for permissions help? Are you encountering an error? Or are you asking for something else? Note that Kali-specific questions are generally off-topic here; Kali has their own support community.

Comment: I would check to ensure you didn't replace any Ubuntu packages with kali ones. Your system may not be Ubuntu any more...  `ubuntu-support-status` and other tools maybe useful to work out what damage you've done to your system (whether it's worth the effort to restore your backups, or just re-install..)

Answer (score 0):

There will be a copy of older sources.list in

```
/etc/apt/
```

Rename that file to sources.list and then:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

After that, reboot.